# python3.9 + matplotlib Não chama o import no .py

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

Então ... versão python 3.9.1
fiz um pip install matplotlib e rodou na boa, Apesar das perguntas com erros de instalação anteriores. Acontece que :

```
import numpy as np 
import math 
import matplotlib as npl
```

Tá dando erro de não achar o módulo, apesar do pip ter dado certo.
Tb acontece para o django não encontrar os módulos...

O que pode ser ??
Obrigado

Comment: Você deve estar instalando a nível de projeto e não a nível global, ou seja, as bibliotecas devem estar disponíveis para outro projeto seu e não o atual.

Comment: Depois de instalar a linguagem de programação, dá uma olhada pra ver se as bibliotecas que você quer usar estão de forma devida no seu PC

Comment: ah ... essa é boa dica e eu fiz um pip install dentro da minha venv ativada